# Problem importing dataset in zip format

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, image-classification, colab

I am trying to import a image dataset in Google Colab in order to do image classification. The dataset is in my Google drive, so I do the following:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

now, i want to import my images and divide them into trainig set and test set, so I do the following:

```
    trainingset = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train'
testset = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Test'

batch_size = 32
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255,\
    zoom_range=0.1,\
    rotation_range=10,\
    width_shift_range=0.1,\
    height_shift_range=0.1,\
    horizontal_flip=True,\
    vertical_flip=False)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=trainingset,
    target_size=(118, 224),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. / 255)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=testset,
    target_size=(118, 224),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=False
)

num_samples = train_generator.n
num_classes = train_generator.num_classes
input_shape = train_generator.image_shape

classnames = [k for k,v in train_generator.class_indices.items()]

print("Image input %s" %str(input_shape))
print("Classes: %r" %classnames)

    print('Loaded %d training samples from %d classes.' % 
   (num_samples,num_classes))
     print('Loaded %d test samples from %d classes.' % 
    (test_generator.n,test_generator.num_classes))
```

but as output I get:

```
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 4 classes.
Image input (118, 224, 3)
Classes: []
Loaded 0 training samples from 0 classes.
Loaded 0 test samples from 4 classes.
```

so, it seems the dataset has not been uploaded. I think the problem is that the dataset is composed by zip files, in particular I have a dataset composed by moder zip files, and each of these contains images. The images are of four classes: Haze, Sunny, Snowy, Rainy. So are images of these four weathers.

To be more clear I can show the dyrectory:

[image]

I am really having troubles understanding how to operate. Can somebody please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need to place image files into the train/test folders (not zipped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Keras documentation [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), `flow_from_directory` should contain one subdirectory per class. Any **PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF** images inside each of the subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator. See this [script](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d) for more details. That means you should probably unzip your zip files.